# Ruby TkButton won't run proc

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit, rubymine

I have a ruby program that uses the TK gui package and I am having trouble with TkButton, specifically the command part.  I am trying to run a method that's in the same class when the button is clicked.  My code is below.  I'm very new to Ruby but not programming in general.  When the button is clicked in the gui I get an Application error that says "Error: NameError: unknown option..." where it identifies the method call in the button as the error cause.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? I'm using RubyMine to develop.

Code:

```
    require 'tk'
    require 'test/unit'
    require_relative 'calc'
    require_relative 'calcTest'

    class CalcUIK


      def test_add
        calc = Calc.new
        expected = Calc.add tk6.get().to_i,tk6.get().to_i
        tk8['textvariable'] = 'Result: ' + expected
      end

      hello = TkRoot.new do
        title "Hello World"
        # the min size of window
        minsize(400,400)
      end
      tk1 = TkLabel.new(hello) do
        text 'Super Calculator'
        foreground 'red'
        pack { padx 15; pady 15; side 'left'}
      end

      tk5 = TkLabel.new(hello) do
        text 'Enter two numbers to math'
        foreground 'blue'
        pack { padx 15; pady 15; side 'left'}
      end

      tk6 = TkEntry.new(hello) do
        foreground 'blue'
        pack { padx 15; pady 15; side 'left'}
      end

      tk7 = TkEntry.new(hello) do
        foreground 'blue'
        pack { padx 15; pady 15; side 'left'}
      end

      tk8 = TkLabel.new(hello) do
        textvariable
        foreground 'blue'
        pack { padx 15; pady 15; side 'left'}
      end

      tk2 = TkButton.new(hello){
        text 'Add'
        command (proc {self.test_add})
        pack('padx'=>'20')
        pack('side'=>'left')
      }
    end
       Tk.mainloop
```

PS I know that this code is kind of dumb but it is just a dummy program to set some more important things up.  The issue I need to resolve is why the button click is not executing the test_add method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You've defined an instance method on your class called `test_add`, but in the context in which your "Add" button is defined, `self` refers to the class `CalcUIK`.</s> **Edit** - now that I think about it, I think since `self` occurs within a block given to `TkButton.new`, `self` refers to the new instance of `TkButton`, which is trying to receive the `test_add` method, but doesn't recognize it as a valid option. Define the proc as `proc { CalcUIK.new.test_add }` to generate a new instance that will run the method.

I would also recommend moving all of the `TkRoot`, `TkButton`, etc. calls either outside the class entirely, or move them into an `initialize` method on `CalcUIK`. Right now, they are run as the class is evaluated, but it's very unusual to have code that is unrelated to the class executed within the context of the class definition.